# How to create folder using dir$n?

Tags: bash

I am creating folder and copying something from Downloads folder. My problem is I wanted to move content of download folder not the folder itself. So I am Trying this

```
n=0
while ! mkdir dir$n
do
    n=$((n+1))

find /home/linaro/Downloads 1 -type f -exec mv -t /home/linaro/dir$n

done
```

The Error is coming like this

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir0’: File exists
find: ‘/home/linaro/Downloads’: No such file or directory
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir1’: File exists
find: ‘/home/linaro/Downloads’: No such file or directory
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir2’: File exists
find: ‘/home/linaro/Downloads’: No such file or directory
mv: failed to access '/home/linaro/dir3': No such file or directory
linaro@tinkerboard:~$
```

Actually command is not able to detect newly created folder (with dynamic name dir$n). I was trying to reach the previous folder. But nothing worked. How to work these?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to copy all the files/Dirs from the Downloads directory? If that is the case you use below code,

```
DirName=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`
mkdir $DirName
mv ~/Downloads/* ~/$DirName
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but I'm not sure what the `1` is following your `/home/linaro/Downloads`. It appears you actually want:

```
find /home/linaro/Downloads -type f -exec mv '{}' /home/linaro/dir$n \;
```

While you can legally write `dir$n`, it makes it much clearer if you write is as `dir${n}`,

```
find /home/linaro/Downloads -type f -exec mv '{}' /home/linaro/dir${n} \;
```

Give it a try and let me know if you have any additional questions.